# Running SpecFlow tests without the feature files included in the solution

Tags: specflow

I run my SpecFlow tests without code-behind - or rather, with code-behind generated at run time.

This lead me to thinking that, if there is an established step definition library, could the `*.feature` files be added to the solution at run time?

Going further, is there an API to pass feature files to SpecFlow dynamically so that it can generate and execute their code at run time?

Comment: Watch this: [SpecFlow without code behind files (SpecFlow xUnitAdapter)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGuoVqG3I8M)

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. It's not actually relevant because I'm already doing that. I want to run feature tests without them being included in the solution - generating even the feature files at run time.

Comment: is this relevant http://gasparnagy.com/2017/04/specflow-without-code-behind-files/ ?

Comment: No, sorry. That’s the same thing. I’m interested in adding feature files after the solution is running.